# SQL Server : geography data type: GeomFromGml

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geospatial

I have troubles to load data into a geography data type:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @x xml;

SET @x = '<gml:MultiSurface gml:id="HVO.20584" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::5514" srsDimension="2" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
<gml:surfaceMember>
<gml:Polygon gml:id="HVO.20584.1">
  <gml:exterior>
    <gml:LinearRing>
      <gml:posList>-747267.00 -1056204.00 -747226.00 -1056232.00 -747239.00 -1056253.00      -747251.00 -1056278.00 -747267.00 -1056315.00 -747291.00 -1056365.00 -747337.00 -1056470.00 -747311.00 -1056474.00 -747244.00 -1056475.00 -747155.00 -1056467.00 -747077.00 -1056501.00 -747112.00 -1057366.00 -747263.00 -1057857.00 -747263.20 -1057857.05 -747263.30 -1057856.60 -747272.50 -1057858.50 -747276.10 -1057850.21 -747285.47 -1057849.89 -747295.34 -1057849.55 -747308.73 -1057848.34 -747320.38 -1057847.28 -747346.97 -1057857.70 -747358.66 -1057860.00 -747374.12 -1057860.55 -747386.06 -1057860.19 -747407.98 -1057859.54 -747444.60 -1057874.26 -747447.75 -1057879.52 -747454.57 -1057890.92 -747674.02 -1057865.46 -747851.54 -1057841.44 -747855.78 -1057838.67 -747871.68 -1057851.47 -747902.20 -1057870.55 -747916.06 -1057881.32 -747934.07 -1057891.87 -747960.03 -1057915.53 -747985.14 -1057954.40 -748001.13 -1057977.02 -748021.22 -1058003.59 -748088.58 -1058092.68 -748104.73 -1058095.49 -748166.00 -1058032.60 -748193.50 -1058002.40 -748214.40 -1057982.20 -748216.40 -1057988.60 -748293.20 -1058053.20 -748297.14 -1058050.03 -748302.55 -1058045.67 -748306.53 -1058042.47 -748311.89 -1058038.15 -748316.50 -1058034.44 -748320.83 -1058030.95 -748330.04 -1058023.54 -748332.15 -1058021.83 -748337.10 -1058017.85 -748341.39 -1058014.39 -748353.30 -1058004.80 -748347.67 -1057996.70 -748338.28 -1057981.31 -748335.70 -1057977.29 -748332.12 -1057971.71 -748330.30 -1057968.92 -748325.55 -1057961.32 -748317.05 -1057947.55 -748310.89 -1057935.02 -748307.10 -1057924.52 -748302.70 -1057912.35 -748298.54 -1057900.12 -748295.48 -1057891.13 -748286.20 -1057862.27 -748278.37 -1057838.25 -748276.55 -1057834.04 -748267.49 -1057808.20 -748264.92 -1057798.33 -748262.21 -1057787.93 -748254.57 -1057761.59 -748251.89 -1057752.13 -748247.59 -1057736.93 -748240.11 -1057716.13 -748237.47 -1057685.67 -748234.93 -1057657.42 -748234.51 -1057652.51 -748234.98 -1057625.54 -748234.51 -1057622.46 -748231.40 -1057602.21 -748233.13 -1057596.29 -748234.13 -1057592.87 -748237.61 -1057582.60 -748238.48 -1057580.02 -748249.72 -1057571.70 -748250.10 -1057571.42 -748252.39 -1057569.73 -748256.83 -1057563.57 -748258.55 -1057540.99 -748250.24 -1057535.67 -748250.94 -1057526.41 -748243.01 -1057522.35 -748236.51 -1057522.75 -748234.73 -1057522.86 -748230.54 -1057518.95 -748211.65 -1057501.36 -748199.48 -1057493.59 -748189.98 -1057489.26 -748179.90 -1057484.66 -748168.54 -1057470.65 -748168.29 -1057470.34 -748165.98 -1057467.49 -748157.92 -1057458.13 -748147.31 -1057450.99 -748146.04 -1057423.54 -748145.40 -1057410.42 -748144.91 -1057400.47 -748144.08 -1057372.43 -748142.62 -1057348.91 -748142.48 -1057347.16 -748141.05 -1057329.37 -748142.26 -1057321.94 -748146.21 -1057304.13 -748148.14 -1057295.42 -748146.30 -1057289.44 -748144.73 -1057284.34 -748141.64 -1057275.31 -748144.63 -1057272.64 -748154.01 -1057247.80 -748151.29 -1057246.55 -748127.50 -1057235.56 -748110.70 -1057228.23 -748082.39 -1057214.75 -748057.48 -1057203.76 -748041.82 -1057196.01 -748029.14 -1057189.74 -748010.10 -1057178.36 -747979.25 -1057161.25 -747957.25 -1057147.63 -747943.14 -1057138.66 -747937.35 -1057131.26 -747926.97 -1057121.60 -747909.48 -1057109.13 -747904.01 -1057106.36 -747895.25 -1057106.99 -747873.33 -1057094.64 -747869.74 -1057093.00 -747851.77 -1057082.31 -747869.79 -1057044.54 -747836.92 -1057032.09 -747795.65 -1057016.73 -747793.70 -1057009.93 -747787.82 -1056992.87 -747781.28 -1056974.44 -747776.81 -1056960.35 -747768.14 -1056933.57 -747762.16 -1056911.71 -747757.80 -1056895.21 -747753.30 -1056877.50 -747749.17 -1056859.18 -747744.25 -1056838.69 -747741.79 -1056821.91 -747739.99 -1056803.90 -747737.12 -1056781.92 -747735.82 -1056761.48 -747735.01 -1056740.42 -747736.57 -1056718.66 -747738.55 -1056694.68 -747741.17 -1056669.07 -747744.02 -1056634.01 -747745.17 -1056623.46 -747748.09 -1056596.69 -747755.37 -1056564.46 -747759.01 -1056547.20 -747761.29 -1056536.38 -747761.56 -1056535.10 -747772.54 -1056491.85 -747774.05 -1056485.90 -747786.35 -1056435.41 -747786.99 -1056433.22 -747796.41 -1056400.93 -747799.01 -1056392.00 -747799.01 -1056392.00 -747799.00 -1056392.00 -747723.00 -1056390.00 -747615.00 -1056374.00 -747596.00 -1056372.00 -747564.00 -1056375.00 -747539.00 -1056382.00 -747513.00 -1056389.00 -747487.00 -1056344.00 -747472.00 -1056316.00 -747458.00 -1056290.00 -747455.00 -1056283.00 -747445.00 -1056265.00 -747433.00 -1056243.00 -747424.00 -1056225.00 -747420.00 -1056218.00 -747412.00 -1056205.00 -747399.00 -1056188.00 -747388.00 -1056173.00 -747383.00 -1056167.00 -747371.00 -1056154.00 -747370.00 -1056153.00 -747362.00 -1056145.00 -747356.00 -1056141.00 -747356.00 -1056140.00 -747334.00 -1056160.00 -747267.00 -1056204.00</gml:posList>
    </gml:LinearRing>
  </gml:exterior>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:surfaceMember>
</gml:MultiSurface>';
SET @g = geography::GeomFromGml(@x, 4326);
```

I get this exception:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "geography":  System.FormatException: 24129: The
>   given XML instance is not valid because the top-level tag is
>   gml:MultiSurface. The top-level element of the input Geographic Markup
>   Language (GML) must contain a Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint,
>   MultiGeometry, MultiCurve, MultiSurface, Arc, ArcString,
>   CompositeCurve, PolygonPatch or FullGlobe (geography Data Type only)
>   object.

What do I need to change in the `@x` variable to get it working?

Thanks

Comment: I think it only recognises the `http://www.opengis.net/gml` namespace, not the `/3.2` one. But then if you adjust that, you'll start getting other errors also.

Comment: Try starting and ending with the <gml:Polygon> tags.

Comment: I tried both to change the namespace and start and end with Polygon tags. But now I get this exception: System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.

Comment: That is because your crs is 5514, see the line with srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::5514". I have no idea what 5514 is: it is not in Postgis's spatial ref sys nor in http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=5514. If you look at the coordinates, it is pretty clear they are in meters and not lat/lon, so you can't use 4326 and you can't use the geography data type. Do you know what 5514 is supposed to be? You can always use something like 3857 (Spherical Mercator), if this turns out to be some global, projected coordinate system and then reproject that to 4326 afterwards (if that is what you want).

Comment: I do not know what 5514 is :-( This is piece of government provided data (some small area within Czech Republic). I have no idea how to store them as geography data type or how to convert them to be able to store them like geography data type.

Comment: OK, I have figured out what 5514 is, given the hint of the Czech Republic  -- I guess your name is something of a clue :D. I have answered your question, giving you a couple of options for how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note, the answer here refers to the question of dealing with the coordinates above, that are not geodesic, as raised in the comments, and not with the original question of parsing the XML, which was answered in the comments.*

After a bit of digging, it seems that the Czech Republic's projection is now known as http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/czech-s-jtsk-gis-esri102067/. If you look at that page you will see that the coordinates are in meters, and are negative, just as in your XML above. This [WKT](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/czech-s-jtsk-gis-esri102067/prettywkt/) representation gives you information about the datum, spheroid and other characteristics of the projection.

SQL Server does not currently support projecting from one coordinate system to another, so you have two options.

1). Load it as is, but as a **geometry** not a geography datatype, so your last line above would become

```
SET @g = geometry::GeomFromGml(@x, 5514);
```

where 9819 appears to be the SRID code in the above link (although it is all a bit unclear). This actually doesn't matter that much, as you can't convert from one spatial reference system to another, but you will be able to perform any geometry functions on your geometries, such as `STIntersects`, `STContains`, `STBuffer`, etc.

2). Convert it to lat/lon (4326) outside of SQL Server and then import as a **geography** data type, if that it what you really want. There is as tool called **gdaltransform** which does this, eg,

```
gdaltransform -s_srs "+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=24.83333333333333 +alpha=0 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=570.8,85.7,462.8,4.998,1.587,5.261,3.56 +units=m +no_defs"  -t_srs EPSG:4326
-747267.00 -1056204.00             
24.8307791587916 50.4239544736181 32.0127759873867
14.3847700978484 49.9644982150517 45.4088854994625
```

where you enter the first line, with the projection info, hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, then enter the coordinates and then you get the answer. From this you can see that it is giving a lat/lon 14.38, 49.96, which is in [Prague](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/49%C2%B057'52.2%22N+14%C2%B023'05.2%22E/@49.9644982,14.3847701,10z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en), so definitely the Czech Republic.

This approach isn't very scalable, so you would probably want to look at something like [Proj4j](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/) which is a Java library for doing coordinate transforms.

Comment: John, thanks for help! The first solution looks much easier, but is it ok to use geometry data type for geographical data? Would you choose this solution if all the data come from one small country?

Comment: Yes. Geometry is totally appropriate if you are using projected coordinates in meters, as you are. Geography is more useful for global data (for obvious reasons). We have the whole of the UK (450 million features) as a geometry datatype because we are also using projected coordinates. The geometry functions are designed to work on planar coordinates, so you should have no trouble at all.